# Capture backlog is higher though captured message metric matches the incoming messages

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-eventhub

In Azure Event Hub Capture, the capture backlog is always high though captured message metric matches the incoming messages. How do we infer this ? Does this mean that Azure is dropping the message payload while capturing to Azure Datalake Gen 1?

[image]

Comment: Before you enable the capture, have you sent some data to event hub?

Comment: @IvanYang Yes. There were events being sent before I started capture.

Answer (score 1):

From Microsoft Azure Metrics [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-metrics-azure-monitor#event-hubs-capture-metrics), I can see that the metric Capture Backlog means

> The number of bytes that are yet to be captured to the chosen destination.

The default aggregation type is Bytes and the unit is bytes.

When capture is enabled over an Event Hub, an empty file file will be created in the capture storage location at time when there are no events to the Event Hub.

From the definition given by Microsoft for **Capture Backlog**, we can see that the value shown for Capture Backlog is the amount of data that is queued for getting captured or stored in the Capture location i.e in your case Azure Datalake Gen 1.

Comment: Thank you Ranjith. But, I am curious why is it different ? Or why is the capture backlog growing?